# Laravel Eloquent thee tables relationship query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three mysql tables :

- **students** (constrained with `USER_ID`)
- **student_in_tournament** (constrained with `STUDENT_ID` and `TOURNAMENT_ID`)
- **tournaments**

I need an eloquent query who take ALL **students** by specified `USER_ID` and if these students are in the **student_in_tournament** table, it needs to join with the **tournament** table.

If these students are not in the **student_in_tournament**, they don't need to join something.

At the end, I need **ALL** students from one specific `USER_ID`, with the tournament joined if he exists in the student_in_tournament table...

I tried a inner join, but it don't give me ALL the students, only these who are in the **student_in_tournament** table. I also tried `Student::with('studentInTournament.tournaments')` but it gives me 'null' in the tournaments

Thanks

Comment: First of all, this is not a "I need this, do it for me", show us what you have tried... Learn [ask]... Also, see the documentation, Laravel has a beautiful documentation, and it is explained there... READ IT... [Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) documentation...

Comment: I tried a inner join, but it don't give me ALL the students, only these who are in the student_in_tournament table. I also tried Student::with('studentInTournament.tournaments') but it gives me 'null' in the tournaments

Comment: Again, read the documentation, everything is explained there, it is super easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a M:N relation between your `Student` and `Tournament` models. Since your table and column names do not conform to what Eloquent expects, you'll need to pass all 4 parameters when creating the relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure

```php
// Student model
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class, 'student_in_tournament', 'STUDENT_ID', 'TOURNAMENT_ID');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship

```php
// Tournament model
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'student_in_tournament', 'TOURNAMENT_ID', 'STUDENT_ID');
}
```

```php
$students = Student::query()
    ->where('USER_ID', $user_id) // or whereIn('USER_ID', $user_ids) if you have multiple user ids
    ->with('tournaments')
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

```xml
@foreach($students as $student)
  <!-- show student information -->
  @forelse($student->tournaments as $tournament)
    <!-- show tournament information -->
  @empty
    <!-- student has no tournaments -->
  @endforelse
  <hr>
@endforeach
```